# Hyperlink and autofilter table based on changing cell value (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

What I am trying to do is create a hyperlink on Sheet1 that autofilters a table on Sheet2. This table should filter based on a certain cell value in Sheet1. The cell value changes dynamically based on slicer selection.

So for instance,

1. if the cell value on Sheet1 displays "Donald Trump", then the table on Sheet2 should filter to display only "Donald Trump" in column 13.
2. If the cell value on Sheet2 displays "Hilary Clinton", then the table on Sheet2 should filter to display only "Hilary Clinton" in column 13. And so on and so forth...

I'm very inexperienced with VBA so I was hoping for some assistance.

Here's what I got so far, but nothing happens when I try and click the hyperlink.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If ActiveSheet.Range("S18").Select = 1 Then
  'This is the cell with the hyerlink in it.
Worksheets("Table of Presidents").ListObjects("Table17").Range.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("S21").Value
 'This is the table that needs to be filtered.
 'The criteria1 part is the field that dynamically changes
Worksheets("Table of Presidents").Activate
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Hillary Clinton is spelled with double l. (But this is not what causes the problem)
2. Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick is an Event Handler that is called whenever you double click somewhere, you don't need this but Worksheet_FollowHyperlink.
3. ActiveSheet.Range("S18").Select means something like click on Cell S18; it has no return value, so you cannot compare it with 1.
4. You don't really need a macro for this. I mean using a macro has some drawbacks: requirements on fileformat, etc. This task can be done by setting the filter based on formulas (using a hidden column or conditional formatting) and adding a link which simply targets a cell on your Table of Presidents sheet.

**Update**

Re 2-3:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Type = msoHyperlinkRange And Target.Range.Address = "$S$18" Then
        Worksheets("Table of Presidents").ListObjects("Table17").Range.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("S21").Value
        Worksheets("Table of Presidents").Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. WHen I run the code it says "Compile error: End With without With"

Comment: OK, I changed the End With to End If. Not sure if I should or not. Either way, it doesn't seem to be working. The hyperlink brings me to Sheet2, but the table is not getting filtered.

Comment: You are right, it's End If. Set a Breakpoint at the first line (If Target...), and let's see if it is called.

Comment: Well, and Address gives an absolute address by default, so I added the two $ signs.

Comment: The weird this is that this code works fine on 1 sheet, but when I run the code on another sheet (and change the ranges and table information) the code does not run anymore... It's the same problem as before: it brings me to the correct table, but no filter gets applied.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128497/discussion-between-darren-and-z32a7ul).